# Where did the second y come from after bringing the exponent into the parentheses?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm not sure how the second step ended up with $2y$ and $y^2$. I can't seem to find the section on the Purplemath site that explains this.

[image]

Comment: What is $(1+y)^2$?

Comment: FOIL that $(-1-y)^2 = (-1-y)\times(-1-y)$

Answer (score 2):

$(-y-1)^2=(-1)^2(y+1)^2=(y+1)^2=y^2+2y+1$